# Why doesn't this code set SharePoint online modern banner image?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, modern-pages

I have tried the following but it doesn't change the actual image on the page when you view it in the browser.

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Id 2 -Values @{"BannerImageUrl" = " https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mycomsite3/bannerimages/bread-braid-tedster-sml.jpg";}
```

What this code does do is change the value you see for page ID2 when you use this code.

```
# Get alist of all pages and their banner URLs
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Fields ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
$items | %{new-object PSObject -Property @{Id=$_["ID"];Title=$_["Title"];BannerImageUrl=$_["BannerImageUrl"].Url}} | select ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
```

My guess is that there is a property related to set-PNPClientSidePage that also needs changing.

Your help suggestions on how to use PNP commandlets would be greatly appreciated.

**Cmdlet versions**

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.18.17... SharePointPnPPowerShell2016         {Add-PnPContentType, Add-PnPContentTypeToDocumentSet,
    Directory: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Apps\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\Modules
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.18.17... SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline       {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection,
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.18.17... SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline       {Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClientSidePageSection,
Binary     2.17.17... SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline       {Add-PnPContentType, Add-PnPContentTypeToDocumentSet,
```

**Cmdlet install**

I think I’ve used the install-module method.

NOTE: I am not trying to remove the banner, that is easy to do using the UI (click the x below the image icon in the page edit view).

Comment: I've checked using SharePoint designer and when I run code like the following

`Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Id 29 -Values @{"BannerImageUrl" = "";}`

The code within the ASPX page is modified to

`<mso:BannerImageUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:BannerImageUrl>`

But the page when viewed in the browser doesn't show no bannerimage.

Comment: It's also logged in pnp as an open issue - https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1464

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity Home.aspx
$lwc = $page.PageListItem.FieldValues.LayoutWebpartsContent
$newLwc = $lwc -replace "&quot;imageSourceType&quot;&#58;4,&quot;", "&quot;imageSourceType&quot;&#58;0,&quot;"
Set-PnPListItem  -List "SitePages" -Id $page.PageId -Values @{"LayoutWebpartsContent" = $newLwc} -SystemUpdate
```

This code here should remove the image from the page.
ImageSourceType = 4 is default,
ImageSourceType = 0 is none,
ImageSourceType = 2 is custom image.

The answer was inspired from https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1464